# django gives an error in virtualenv

Tags: python, django

I do have Win7 64 bit. Sequence of my action is below

1. I have installed python 2.7.3. system path is clear.
2. Then i did install virtualenv and pip
3. Next is sequence of mine command

   - cd c:\Users\developer\
   - mkdir .virtualenv
   - cd .virtualenv
   - virtualenv --distribute --no-site-packages djangos
   - cd djangos
   - cd script
   - activate.bat
   - pip install django

now i include into system path env a directory

**c:\Users\developer\.virtualenv\django\scripts**

here is the problem. if type in console

cd c:\Project

**django-admin.py startproject helloworld**

then i am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\developer\.virtualenv\djangos\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 2, in     <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

but if i do run 
python
and the inside interpreter

```
>>import django
>>django.VERSION
>>(1, 4, 0, 'final', 0)
>>from django import core
>>from django.core import managment
```

I dont receive any error

only way to create project it is to run 
**(djangos) c:\Projects>python  c:\Users\developer.virtualenv\djangos\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject hello**

if there is a way to avoid every time to type full path in cli?

Comment: `activete.bat` ? shouldn't it be `activate.bat`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
django-admin.py startproject helloworld
```

Try

```
python django-admin.py startproject helloworld
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Windows make automatic files associations for *.py* files to a specific *python.exe* executable. Even if you activate a *virtualenv*, errors will be raised when trying to execute the command:

```
django-admin.py
```

The reason is that the *python.exe* used to execute the script is still the one associated with *.py* files by Windows. In my case, the default Windows association is *C:\Python27\python.exe*. This is despite having configured and activated the virtualenv to point to *C:\Users\developer.virtenv\django\scripts\python.exe*.

To correctly execute `djano-admin.py`, either use a full path like:

```
C:\users\developer\.virtenv\django\scripts\python.exe django-admin.py
```

Or, delete the default Windows association to *.py* files. That way, when *virtualenv* is activated, it will amend the *%PATH%* variable to point to the *python.exe* in the virtual environment.

~~~

(*Note: This problem doesn't generally occur on Linux machines. It's particular to the way Windows works.*)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your activation of the virtualenv failed. Thus Django was installed in site-packages which you specifically excluded. Try to create a virtualenv without --no-site-packages to test if this is the case.

You can always create an alias or symlink to shortcut commands, try google